# How can I get views that depend on other views and functions that depend on other functions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How can I get the dependencies between views and functions in PostgreSQL?

I tried searching the `pg_catalog` but all I got was: 
The dependencies `view -> function`, `aggregate -> function`.
What I wanted was the dependencies:
`function -> function`
`function -> view`
`view -> view`

How can get them without doing the ugly: `definition.Contains(functionName)`?